# Do I have to make N TextEditingControllers if I have N TextFields or Is there any efficient way to do this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Say if I have ten Text fields in my flutter application,so I have to make ten Text Editing Controller to control the text fields like to get the text from them. However, it may be possible that I would have hundreds of TextField in my application, so, would I have to 100 TextEditingControllers like in below-mentioned code? If not then what is the best way to solve this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {

  final TextEditingController firstController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController secondController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController thirdController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController fourthController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController fifthController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController sixthController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController seventhController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController eightController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController ninthController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController tenthController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Form(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: firstController,
            ),

            TextFormField(
              controller: secondController,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: thirdController,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: fourthController,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: fifthController,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: sixthController,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: seventhController,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: eightController,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: ninthController,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: tenthController,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still they need to be N! Is there a way to minimize the code?

Comment: That's a lot of code! Basically I have to generate a form based on the no of items in the List. So, the items in list can be many. So I am just trying to find a better way of it, if exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle multiple `TextFormField` in flutter, we can use a widget called `Form` with only one `GlobalKey` to check and save all the data in the `TextFormField`.

I would like to explain it, however, I am sure that [reading this flutter cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation) you will understand it much better.

**Edit**

As I see there are some doubts, I will explain briefly how to save the data, that would be the next step on that cookbook.

1. We create a `Form` with a `GlobalKey` as explained in the
   cookbook.
2. We validate the data using `_formKey.currentState.validate()`
   and the `validator` property on each `TextFormField`.
3. We save the text in each `TextFormField` using
   `_formKey.currentState.save()` and the `onSaved` property.

The `TextFormField` would look like this:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'What do people call you?',
    labelText: 'Name *',
  ),
  onSaved: (String value) {
    // Use this code to save the text wherever you need it, a Map, List, db...
  },
  validator: (String value) {
    if (value.contains('@') {
      return 'Do not use the @ char.';
    }
    return null;
  },
)
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: how do you get the content of each Textfield to save/submit it somewhere without a TextEditingController?

Comment: How to get text from each TextFormField?

Comment: It makes sense! Thanks!